# Send money to user's Apple Pay account

Tags: ios, iphone, applepay

I'd like to enable my application to put money INTO a user's Apple Pay account. At first I thought I could just have the user 'pay' a negative amount, but as it says in the docs, the grand total has to be a positive number.

So, how can I send a user money using Apple Pay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible at the moment. Apple Pay Cash (a peer to peer payment system) is due out later this month (https://9to5mac.com/2017/09/28/apple-pay-cash-late-october-launch/) although it seems unclear whether or not apps will be able to deposit money.